# How many members are there in the swimming club given the following conditions?

Tags: percentages

[image: How many members are there in the swimming club?]

**MyApproach**

$3/10$ of the members have passed the test.

$\implies 7/10$ of the members have not passed the test.

Out of $7/10$ of the members, $12$ have taken preparatory course and $30$ have not taken preparatory course.

$\implies 7/10\cdot X=30+12$ where $X$ are the total no of people.

$\implies X=60$

> Am I correct in my approach?

Comment: this looks perfectly valid to me, good job.

Comment: In short, $42$ people comprise $70\%$ of the club, hence $42\cdot\frac{100}{70}=60$ comprise $100\%$ of the club.

Comment: @justintakro, Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: I don't understand.  Wouldn't it have been much easier to type in the question?  Why put it as an image?  Are you trying to hide something or do you just want people to have more difficulty in answering your question?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I was having less time that time.So,I clicked the picture from my book and posted this question.I will keep in mind next time.Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Shortly,

$\frac 7{10}th$ of total =$30+12$

So,total=$60$

Comment: You repeat the last two steps of the OP's solution.  Since the Question asks about correctness of the approach, I suppose you are saying the approach is okay.